# Update twitter status via TwitteR

Tags: r, twitter

I want to update my Twitter status via R. First I initialize my connection:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("httr")
install_github("twitteR", username="geoffjentry")
library(twitteR)
api_key <- "HIDDEN"
api_secret <- "HIDDEN"
access_token <- "HIDDEN"
access_token_secret <- "HIDDEN"
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)
```

Then I update my status with:

```
updateStatus("Blah Blah Blah")
```

I can do this for once but in the second time I get this error:

```
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(endpoint, params = params, method = "POST",  : 
  client error: (403) Forbidden
```

Then I should wait for hours and again I can update my status for once. How may I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I did have a similar problem and I found out something that has helped me out.

- Log in to twitter and open apps.twitter.com in your browser. Choose the application that you have created for updating your twitter status via R.
- In the section *Details*, below *Application Settings*, there is *Access Level*. Click on *modify app permissions*. Choose ***Read, write, and direct messages*** and save the new settings.
- Regenerate the Consumer Key and Access Token. Update you R code with new generated numbers and run you code again.

This might work. I am a new R user with little prior programming experience, but it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying again by making sure you are posting different Tweets every time.

Twitter considers it may be a mistake when you are attempting to post twice in a row the exact same Tweet text, so that might be your issue when performing tests of your code?

If this does not help, please share with us the actual HTTP response to have more information about this 403 error since we include additional error codes in the body to give more insights.