# Unexplained difference between tweet functions in R package twitteR

Tags: r, twitter

I am testing the twitteR package with the following code

```
library(twitteR)
## Connecting
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key = '***',
                    consumer_secret = '***',
                    access_token = '***',
                    access_secret = '***')
## Sending multiple tweets
for( i in 1:2){
  msg <- paste("this is the test", i, "server")
  tweet(msg)  
}
```

I did that on my laptop and on an ubuntu server, worked like a charm.
The twitterR documentation says that the functions tweet and updateStatus are the same, so I tried again

```
for( i in 1:2){
  msg <- paste("this is the test", i, "server")
  updateStatus(msg)  
}
```

and then got the error

```
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(endpoint, params = params, method = "POST",  : 
  Forbidden (HTTP 403).
```

Furthermore (using examples I don't have reproducible ones here), I have experienced much more unstability with updateStatus() compared to tweet().

It hence looks to me like there is something very different between these functions, did I misunderstood anything?

Comment: Author of that package says to switch to `rtweet`... https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR

Comment: I don't know for the differences, but it looks like the error can be linked to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600659/update-twitter-status-via-twitter

Comment: Twitter probably has a rate limit so bots don't fill it up with trash like this...